# Display Toast while awaiting Navigation.PushAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display a Toast while waiting for the MainPage to load. However, the process of adding the main page does not begin until after the default 3 seconds for the Toast has elapsed.

Is it possible to display the Toast for the duration it takes for the MainPage to be added to the top of the navigation stack?

```
   // using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Extensions;

   await this.DisplayToastAsync("Loading");
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

Comment: Try removing await for this.DisplayToastAsync("Loading");

Comment: Removing await does not appear to fix it. It makes the Toast appear after MainPage has been displayed. I would like the Toast to be displayed while the processing is being performed, if that is possible.

Comment: Try to make your own with `DependencyService`

Comment: Add min delay of approx 10 (await Task.Delay(10)) in between those two call and try.

Comment: @ApRD Navigation.PushAsync will need little time to navigate to another page, but DisplayToastAsync will display a period of time, so you will see DisplayToastAsync("Loading") after MainPage displayed.

Comment: @ApRD Any update? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend Acr.UserDialogs library .Please try this.

```
         try  {

         UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading", MaskType.Gradient); 
            await DoAnyThing();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
   //return error
            }
            finally
            {
               UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            }
```